# Appending object with Javascript array to a QML ListModel causes SEGFAULT

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am using QtQuick on Android.

I am trying to append a Javascript object with an array property to a `ListModel`.

I use `LocalStorage` to store this data.

The object I materialise from the database has this array property, and when I try and append that object to the `ListModel` I get a SEGFAULT. If I do not include an array in my object, or in fact if the array is empty, then it will successfully append to the `ListModel` and will not SEGFAULT.

When I materialise the object from the database, I do this:

```
var movie = {
    id: row.id,
    title: row.title,
    genres: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

I'm creating a Javascript object and copying properties from the `LocalStorage` result-set object 'row'. For the sake of this issue, I just hard-code the array as you can see above. When this object is appended to the `ListModel` it SEGFAULTs.

If I remove the genres attribute completely, or even leave it empty as in [], it will not SEGFAULT when appended:

```
var movie = {
    id: row.id,
    title: row.title,
    genres: []
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
0   ListModel::set(int, QV4::Referenced<QV4::Object>, QV8Engine*)   /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7542b138  
1   ListModel::append(QV4::Referenced<QV4::Object>, QV8Engine*) /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7542b40a  
2   ListModel::set(int, QV4::Referenced<QV4::Object>, QV8Engine*)   /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7542b26c  
3   ListModel::append(QV4::Referenced<QV4::Object>, QV8Engine*) /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7542b40a  
4   QQmlListModel::append(QQmlV4Function*)  /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7542d21c  
5   QQmlListModel::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)  /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x754347ea  
6   QMetaObject::metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Core.so        0x75054416  
7   QV4::QObjectMethod::callInternal(QV4::CallData*)    /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x753ac7c4  
8   QV4::FunctionObject::call(QV4::CallData*)   /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x7537ed5e  
9   QV4::__qmljs_call_property(QV4::ExecutionContext*, QV4::Referenced<QV4::String>, QV4::CallDataRef)  /home/linux/qt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/android_armv7/lib/libQt5Qml.so     0x75380962  
10  ??          0x7727c2e8  
11  ??          0x7727c2e8
```

After building Qt with full debug symbols and single-stepping, the crash is here:

```
void ListModel::set(int elementIndex, QV4::ObjectRef object, QV8Engine *eng)
{
    ListElement *e = elements[elementIndex];

    QV4::ExecutionEngine *v4 = object->engine(); <= SEGFAULT
```

When stepping through the code it seems when it encounters the Javascript array value for the genres property, the `ListModel` is attempting to create a sub-model and then it fails. This is called as a result of this piece of code also in the `ListModel::set` function:

```
} else if (propertyValue->asArrayObject()) {
    a = propertyValue;
    const ListLayout::Role &r = m_layout->getRoleOrCreate(propertyName, ListLayout::Role::List);
    if (r.type == ListLayout::Role::List) {
        ListModel *subModel = new ListModel(r.subLayout, 0, -1);

        int arrayLength = a->arrayLength();
        for (int j=0 ; j < arrayLength ; ++j) {
            o = a->getIndexed(j);
            subModel->append(o, eng); <= This leads to the nested 'set' call above that crashes
        }
```

So why is this failing?

Comment: can you maybe provide a stacktrace of the crash? if you start the app in debug mode you should be able to see the c++ stacktrace in Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails because it is not supported to store non-object values such as literal strings or integers as property values in an array.

An array property *can* be stored, but only if each item in the array is an *object*, not a primitive or string literal.

This works:

```
var movie = {
    id: row.id,
    title: row.title,
    genres: [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
}
```