# Can one add a complex type item to ListModel?

Tags: json, listview, qml, qtquick2

I would like to have a `ListModel`-like structure to display inputs of a simple state machine. Each input might consist of several strings/ints. So I need each item of the `ListModel` to be able to store a list of data (strings with names of the input's parameters, or dictionaries with strings etc). At the moment I cannot append an item with a list property to a `ListModel`.

So the `ListModel` looks like this:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    model: ListModel {
        id: listModel
    }

    delegate: Text {
        text: inputs[0]['name']
    }
}
```

And when the state changes I want to update the model and append elements like this:

```
var state = {
    name: "abcd",
    inputs: [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
}
listModel.append(state);
```

Current version of the code returns error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. It does not see the list.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984327/appending-object-with-javascript-array-to-a-qml-listmodel-causes-segfault) there might be issues with using lists in the items of `ListModel`. But it seems irrelevant to my case. Maybe I need to use lists and dicts differently in QML, maybe I had to write `text: inputs[0].name` in delegate (which I tried) or something else (suggestions?).

Could someone suggest how to make a more or less complex item (basically, it is standard JSON) in a `ListModel`? It is not clear, since documentation and blogs/questions deal with strings all the time. Is there some helpful documentation which I missed? What are good practices to do it in QML? Should I use some custom objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List data can be added to a `ListElement`, according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#example-usage) and as you correctly did in your imperative code. However, nested roles are not really arrays. They are `ListModel`s themselves. That's because, [by design](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html#change-notification-semantics), QML does not produce a notification if an element of an array changes, which would be a show-stopper in a model-view-delegate setting.

Since the nested role is a model, you can use model's functions. For instance, this example works fine:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: window
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            id: listModel
        }

        delegate: Text {
            text: name + inputs.get(index % inputs.count).name  // accessing the inner model
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var state = {
                name: "abcd",
                inputs: [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
            }
            listModel.append(state);
        }
    }
}
```

According to your question, the input is plain JSON. In that case, consider the usage of [`JSONListModel`](https://wiki.qt.io/JSONListModel) in place of `ListModel`. It exposes a set of API which matches `XMLListModel`, via JSONPath, and could possibly represent the perfect solution for your scenario.