# Model of horizontal listview inside vertical listview

Tags: c++, listview, model, qml, qt5

I want to make horizontal listview as a delegate of vertical listview. Is it possible to attach different models to horizontal listview from c++?

```
 ListView {
            id: eventList
            model: N (N tells how many horizontal lists are there)
            delegate:
                ListView {
                id: horizontall
                model: ?? // How to attach different model from C++ to each horizontal list
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
```

In c++ part I have implementet N number of QList  list that are derived from QAbstractlistmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. It is just not possible to make a `ListModel` containing another `ListModel`. At least it is not possible in QML.

Here is quick and dirty example of how to make it. Does it solve your problem?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {slmIndex: 0}
        ListElement {slmIndex: 1}
        ListElement {slmIndex: 2}
        ListElement {slmIndex: 3}
        ListElement {slmIndex: 4}
        ListElement {slmIndex: 5}
    }

    ListModel {
        id: model1
        ListElement { name: "1" }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model2
        ListElement { name: "1" }
        ListElement { name: "2" }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model3
        ListElement { name: "1" }
        ListElement { name: "2" }
        ListElement { name: "3" }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model4
        ListElement { name: "1" }
        ListElement { name: "2" }
        ListElement { name: "3" }
        ListElement { name: "4" }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model5
        ListElement { name: "1" }
        ListElement { name: "2" }
        ListElement { name: "3" }
        ListElement { name: "4" }
        ListElement { name: "5" }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: model6
        ListElement { name: "1" }
        ListElement { name: "2" }
        ListElement { name: "3" }
        ListElement { name: "4" }
        ListElement { name: "5" }
        ListElement { name: "6" }
    }
    property var secondLayerModels: [
        model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6
    ]

    ListView {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 200
        height: 200
        clip: true
        model: listModel
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        delegate: ListView {
            width: 200
            height: 50
            model: secondLayerModels[slmIndex]
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: 50
                border.color: "black"
                Text {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    text: name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am not sure if this answer covers completely the question. It does not cover how to create C++ model that will expose another models.

Comment: Having nested `ListModel`s is possible via `attributes`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34358794/2538363) and related links. That said, It seems to me that having nested models is an unnecessary addition of complexity. I would register the c++ models and then use them in a custom view with `Flickable` + `Repeater`. In a more dynamic setting, e.g. if the c++ models can change drastically in number, it would be good to have a unique class exposing the number of models and granting access to them. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Filip Hi, the problem is that I don't know how many models I am going to have - that depends on some data in C++. 
I know it is possible to add ListElement to ListModel but I can't find appropriate way to create N ListModels and then add elements to each model. In example you hardcoded 6 models with property var secondLayerModels. ##
BaCaRoZzo: I have tried with Listview inside repeater and it also works fine with array of models and getting each model due to index. Do you know something about what I asked Filip? It seems like a simple problem, but I cannot reach the solution.